# How to change img src depending on condition in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to make my Jekyll website responsive to the user's theme choice (light, dark), and I'm wondering why this code isn't working:

```
<img 
    {% if site.style == 'dark' %}
        src="{{ "/assets/images/logo-dark.svg" | relative_url }}"
    {% elsif site.style == 'light' %}
        src="{{ "/assets/images/logo.svg" | relative_url }}"
    {% endif %} 
    alt="logo"/>
```

I'm trying to change the src depending on the theme. Am I doing something wrong? I can't figure it out.

Also, the assets are in the correct spot (putting the src as `{{ "/assets/images/logo.svg" | relative_url }}` works correctly.

**Edit (fixed):**

Make sure you choose the correct images for the correct themes, I should have switched `site.style == 'dark'` with `site.style == 'light'`.

Comment: How do you let the user set the site theme? How is `site.style` set? And what is the value of `site.style` currenlty?

Comment: @Dominik Right now it's hardcoded in the `_config.yml` file. Later on, it will be able to be chosen.

Comment: What is it's value?

Comment: @Dominik I found out the problem, I had to switch around "dark" and "light"

Comment: That makes no sense here. Would be good for you to answer this question so others who may find this can see what the issue was

Comment: @Dominik Okay, I didn't know you can do that